# Can't get entries to list

Tags: channel-entries, ee

I am a EE dev novice. I have created a practice website to learn EE. I am having trouble getting the entries for my channel to show here in the "endorsements section":

http://www.mannawebsites.com/_development_sites/ee3_site/index.php/blog/blog-entry/driving-cars

I am not sure if the error is in the dashboard side of things or in the code.

I made a channel called "endorsements", made a field group called "endorsements". Assigned that field within the channel, made the fields "endorsement_image"/"endorsement_name"/"endorsement", then made one entry, and hard coded the following code in my template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="endorsements" related_categories_mode="yes" dynamic="no" custom_fields="yes" sort="asc" limit="3" status="open"}
        <div class="4u 12u(mobile)">

        <section class="highlight">
        <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="{endorsement_image:mid-size}" alt="{title} photo" /></a>
        <h3>{endorsement_name}</h3>
                <p>{endorsement}</p>
                <ul class="actions">
                <li><a href="#" class="button style1">Learn More</a></li>
                </ul>
        </section>
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Nothing shows in the browser despite all my efforts to troubleshoot. Also, I'm not sure which attributes are necessary here to make this work, I'm just throwing everything I can at it. I have category group "endorsements" category group and a custom field group? Do I even need that for this?

Can someone help me find where the problem is to make this show in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Too many stinkin' attributes! I "think" the related_categories_mode attribute with the dynamic attribute did some type of EE collision. Live and learn, people... live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing to many attributes. Try something this:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="endorsements"
    disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks|relationships"
    dynamic="no" limit="3"
}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```